# How to access subtitles of Khan Academy videos?

Tags: youtube, subtitle, khan-academy

I'm curious to know, how to download the subtitles for the videos of Khan Academy. As far as I know, universalsubtitles[dot]org has the subtitles. But I'm unable to get any results from my API calls. Here are a few sample calls that I tried which do not give any result but rather says that 'We're sorry - the page you are trying to access does not exist':

> - http://www.universalsubtitles.org/api/1.0/subtitles/?video_url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYZF6oIZtfc&feature=youtube_gdata_player
> - http://www.universalsubtitles.org/api/1.0/subtitles/?video_url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYZF6oIZtfc&feature=youtube_gdata_player&language=en

I tried quite a few other formats of the above API calls too, but none of them seem to work. So could someone please help me out on how to access subtitles of Khan Academy videos. I would also appreciate your answers, even if they have other ways of accessing Khan Academy videos' subtitles other than accessing it from universalsubtitles[.]org

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **NOT** about any concrete programming problem ....

Comment: If that's so, then could you please suggest me a platform where I can discuss about these topics. I've done quite a lot of research and only then asked this question.

Comment: I would say that it is on-topic because "This tag is for questions related to interfacing with Khan Academy, such as through the Khan Academy API" and the questioner just didn't know of a Khan API call to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the undocumented API call "http://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/videos/%s/transcript" where %s is the YouTube ID of the video. You will get the transcript lines for the video with start and end times for each line. I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: Amazing, it's working. Thanks for your effort :) But now I've lost the interest to update the Khan app that I had started way back in 2014. Yet, I had already found other ways of getting the subtitles, albeit unreliably. Cheers :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I didn't see the question sooner!